# Autofocus form field causes loading issue in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I have a Laravel-based web application, and I have a very odd and specific problem appearing on some pages in Firefox only.

If I have a form on the page, and in that form there is a field with autofocus, the HTML loads before the CSS, and for a second or two, the user sees the page as plain text, before the CSS loads and then everything is back to normal.

The correlation sounds far-fetched, but removing the autofocus from the form field resolves the issue in 100% of cases on the website. Is the autofocus somehow requiring the browser to load the HTML before the styling? How do I fix this without removing autofocus from all my forms?

This is an example form field from the site:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="card-number" class="col-md-4 control-label">Card Number</label>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="card-number" type="text" class="form-control span4 card-number numbers-only" value="" required autofocus maxlength="16">
                        @if ($errors->has('card-number'))
                            <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('card-number') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
```

All the CSS files are loaded in the `<head>` of the page:

```
<!-- jQuery UI -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<!-- Theme Styles -->
<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using? A quick Google search reveals this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=712130 which might be related. Fixed in Firefox 60.

Comment: I'm using 59.0.2 for Mac OS. I can upgrade but I may have a bunch of users using Firefox <60, do you know if there's a workaround available because this is unacceptable even if it only affects 1% of the users.

Comment: Never encountered this bug and I don't use autofocus, so I can't really answer that conclusively. You could potentially use JavaScript to focus on a input field once the page has loaded fully.

Comment: I suppose that would work. Upgrading to FF60 fixed it for me, that will do for now and I'll figure out what to do with the buggy versions later. Thanks.